# how to display students in increasing order based on correct answers in python

Tags: python

okay so I'm writing this code but am not sure how to put the students in order of least to greatest correct answers. The out put should be "Student 3's number of correct answers is 4" and so on.
Here's my current code:

```
def main():
  answers = [
    ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
    ['D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
    ['E', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
    ['C', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
    ['A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
    ['B', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
    ['B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
    ['E', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D']]
  key = ['D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'D']
  for i in range(len(answers)):
    correctCount = 0
    for j in range(len(answers[i])):
      if answers[i][j] == key[j]:
        correctCount +=1
    print("Student", i, "'s correct count is", correctCount)
main()
```

Comment: Please post your desired output. "In a certain order", what order?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.   Read the `sort` part of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types); search on line for a sorting tutorial if you need more help.  Make a valid coding attempt; *then* you have a good post.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace available tutorials.

Comment: lowest number of correct answers to highest

Comment: `scores = [sum(k==a for k, a in zip(key, ans)) for ans in answers]`  To sort do `answers.sort(key=lambda ans: sum(k==a for k, a in zip(key, ans)))`.

Comment: @ZakRule check out my [github](https://github.com/darclander) if you need help with your java.

Answer (score 2):

I think is best you split the problem in steps:

1. Determine the number of correct answers
2. Sort the output

Given the previous steps, you could do the following:

```
answers = [
    ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
    ['D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
    ['E', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
    ['C', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
    ['A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
    ['B', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
    ['B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'],
    ['E', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D']]


def number_of_correct_answers(answers, golden=['D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'D']):
    """Return the number of correct answers given a gold standard"""
    return sum(g == a for g, a in zip(golden, answers))


for student_answer in sorted(answers, key=number_of_correct_answers, reverse=True):  # the best come first
    print(student_answer, 'Number of correct', number_of_correct_answers(student_answer))
```

**Output**

```
['A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'] Number of correct 8
['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'] Number of correct 7
['B', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'] Number of correct 7
['B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'] Number of correct 7
['E', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'] Number of correct 7
['D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'] Number of correct 6
['E', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'] Number of correct 5
['C', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'] Number of correct 4
```

The key of the functionaly above relies on the functions: [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted). In the example above the better students come first, if you want the other way around just remove the `reverse=True` parameter.

**See:**

1. [Sorting - HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: This is good but I don't want their answers to be output. I want "Student 4's correct count is 8" and so on

Comment: @ZakRule You can get want you want, you just have to tweak the code a bit.